# Angular-js - Populating Checkbox and track it based on JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested Objects in JSON, and I need to populate the checkbox based on what comes in (dynamic) from JSON file, meaning, I wouldn't know in advance the name of the fields, or how many elements there could be. Here is a sample, but there could be more child and each child could have more or less item in it.

```
{
"Parent":{

 "Child" : 

        {
            "Child_01" : {

                "description_01":false,
                "description_02":false,
                "description_03":false,
                "description_04":false,
                "description_05":false
            },


            "Child_02" : 
              {
                "something_01":false,
                "something_02":false,
                "something_03":false,
                "something_04": false
              },

              "Child_03" : 
              {
                "things_01":false,
                "things_02":false,
                "things_03":false,
                "things_04":false,
                "things_05":false
              }

        }

}
}
```

Now, I need to populate a drop down from it, (child_01, child_02, child_03....) and when user choose one of them, I need to display checkboxes of all its properties. And of course be able to keep track of the chosen one.

Here is what I have.

```
$scope.children = response.data.parent.child;
$scope.childrenList = [];

angular.forEach($scope.children, function(value1, key1){
     $scope.childrenList.push(key1);

});
```

and html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in children">
               <input ng-model="childrenListModel" type="checkbox" name="{{child}}" value="{{child}}">{{child}}</input>

</div>
```

Nothing works the way I intend to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need several nested `ng-repeat`s.  Have a look at this working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K92JI7UlW9h6gh8SPeU5?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="child in children.Parent.Child">

  <div ng-repeat="options in child">

    <div ng-repeat="option in options">

      <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in option">

        <label for="{{key}}">
          {{key}}
          <input name="{{key}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="option[key]" />
        </label>


      </div>

    </div>
    <hr />

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is great, I get it all. How can I have a dropdown so I see the properties of the chosen child only?

Comment: Two ways: (1) Instead of `child in children.Parent.Child`, you do `child in getChild()`.  getChild() would need to return an array of the chosen child.  (2) In the child dropdown, have `ng-model="selectedChild"`, then in the options dropdown, do `ng-options="option in selectedChild"`.

Comment: Is it too much to ask if you can do option one in a plunker? the one with getChild()

Comment: I did the second way but getting error:                                                              'code' <div ng-repeat="child in children.Parent.Child" ng-model="selectedChild" >  
      <div ng-repeat="options in child" ng-options="option in selectedChild">
        <div ng-repeat="option in options" >
          <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in option">
            <label for="{{key}}">
              {{key}}
              <input name="{{key}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="option[key]" />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: Solved, I chose the first approach, so I am using "forEach" in the js file for the ng-change option. Same nested loop and save the chosen item properties in an array,